# Testing jQuery Animations with Jest

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jquery-animate, jestjs

I would like to test jQuery animation states without waiting for them to finish using the Jest test framework. I've tried to use `jest.useFakeTimers` and all of the associated timer methods but had no success.

```js
$(() => {
  const $button = $('button');
  const $ul = $('ul');
  
  $button.click(() => {
    $ul.slideToggle();
  });
  
  // Random Test - Not Jest
  $button.click();
  console.log("Visible", $ul.is(':visible') === true);
  $button.click();
  console.log("Hidden", $ul.is(':visible') === false);
});
```

```css
ul { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle</button>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery provides an `fx.off` setting that will force animations to automatically jump to their final state.

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  $.fx.off = true;
});

afterAll(() => {
  $.fx.off = false;
});

test('whatever you want', () => {
 // ....
})
```

The docs are here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.off/

Answer (score 0):

You can mock/hook `jQuery.speed` so that all animations are instant.

```js
$(() => {
  const $button = $('button');
  const $ul = $('ul');
  
  $button.click(() => {
    $ul.slideToggle();
  });

  // Hook/Mock jQuery.speed
  const OGSpeed = jQuery.speed;
  jQuery.speed = function(_speed, easing, callback) {
    return OGSpeed(0, easing, callback);
  };

  // Random Test - Not Jest
  $button.click();
  console.log("Visible", $ul.is(':visible') === true);
  $button.click();
  console.log("Hidden", $ul.is(':visible') === false);
});
```

```css
ul { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle</button>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```